# Does the attacker automatically know where Archfey Warlock teleports to with Misty Escape?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, stealth, invisibility, teleportation

> [...] you can vanish in a puff of mist in response to harm. When you take damage, you can use your reaction to turn invisible and teleport up to 60 feet to an unoccupied space you can see. [...]

To specify the scenario, let's assume the Warlock is not hidden, damage comes from an attack, and the Warlock teleports maximum distance away from the attacker/attack.

Does the attacker in most or all situations know where the Warlock teleports to?

**What would be the conditions where the attacker would *not* know the Warlocks new location?**

Comment: Highly related: [Does casting Mislead within enemy eyesight reveal the illusion to be false?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/193464/23547).

Answer (score 7):

### They will know, if and when the warlock makes noise

The [invisible condition](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Invisible) says:

> The creature's location can be detected by any noise it makes or any tracks it leaves.

Generally, if a creature is moving, it is making noise.  Even if a creature stands still, simply breathing, the leather straps on its pack are creaking, its metal armor is clinking, etc.  It is usually assumed that all creatures know the presence of any other creature 'on the board' that is not Hiding, even those that are invisible, simply by being alert for danger and listening.  If your warlock wanted to be unheard as well as invisible, they would need to Hide, spending their action to attempt stealth.  Since they are invisible, they can Hide even if they are within line of sight of opponents.  But they are unlikely to have an action immediately available to Hide, since they teleported in response to taking damage, and that would more often happen on their opponent's turn rather than their own.

If there is an active battle going on, your DM could reasonably rule that the warlock's location is unknown until it starts moving, since the sounds of battle might obscure the noise the warlock makes just by standing still in its new location.

Further discussion can be found on a number of questions, such as:

[How to guess the location of invisible enemies?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/133302/23547)

[Does casting Mislead within enemy eyesight reveal the illusion to be false?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/193464/23547)